# заставить работать js код по маске

Tags: javascript

Имеется url-ы вида
[http://localhost/users/тут](http://localhost/users/%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82) разные логины
Как произвести код который будет работать по следующему алгоритму.
"Если ссылка http://localhost/users/* то делать следующий код"
Пытаюсь сделать вот так
    
    if(location.pathname == "/user/") {
        alert("asd");
    }
    
Но к сожалению код не работает. Всем спасибо.

Comment: А вы проверьте значение своей переменной location.pathname через консоль браузера, вызвав `console.log(location.pathname)` и сравните с == "/user/" который вы пытаетесь сделать. Я думаю там еще  понадобится дополнительный парсинг строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понимаю, тебе нужна возможность роутинга. 
По коду не совсем понятно, но скорее всего данный код не отрабатывает потому, что никогда не бывает вызван. 
Намного проще будет использовать готовые решения, например, [route-recognizer](https://github.com/tildeio/route-recognizer).

В данном случае код будет выглядеть так:

```js
var router = new RouteRecognizer();

router.add([{
  path: "/users/:login",
  handler: function(login) {
    console.log(login);
  }
}]);
```

Либо, используй событие hashchange

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
 alert(location.pathname); #/users/userLogin
});
```

Например, при смене url с

```
/users
```

на

```
/users/userLogin#
```

В консоли мы увидим "/users/userLogin"

Либо, на каждую необходимую ссылку повесить обработчик ее нажатия.

Comment: Это ведь библиотека, можно как нибудь нативно решить данный вопрос?

Comment: Да, конечно. Поправил свой ответ.

Comment: К сожалению тоже не подходит))

Comment: Значит нужно более подробно описать проблему. Почему не подходит?

Comment: Имеется множество ссылок вида http://site.ru/xfsearch/value я это value получаю путем window.title и подставляю методом text в div, хеш задать просто технически не получится

Comment: Где находятся эти ссылки и в каком случае должен выполняться код? Одно дело, когда ты вводишь ссылку в адресную строку руками и переходишь по ней, и совсем другое, когда нажимаешь на ссылку.

Comment: Переход по ссылкам осуществляется нажатием

Comment: К примеру код должен выполняться если в строке браузера имеется строка /users/***

Comment: К примеру имеется ссылка http://site.ru/users/admin скрипт должен выполнить условие проверки, к примеру если в строке замечена строка users то выполнить alert('test')

Comment: На этот раз пример должен подойти.